# Access ASP.NET control using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a basic javascript function like this which works as I am able to dynamically change the textbox in a javascript method at runtime.

```
function MyTst(pVal2) {           
        var x = document.getElementById('<%=myImage.ClientID%>');
        x.src = "/images/write.gif";      

    }
```

In the above code I need to be generic. So replace '<%=myImage.ClientID%>' with the input param to my method which in this instance is called pVal2 and contains the asp.net server control image id.

Can anyone advise on an approach to do this. I've tried lots of things and just cant seem to get it working.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Client-side vs Server-side. The ASP.NET code has already run before JavaScript even gets the chance to think about running. The code you're trying to find with javascript no longer exists.

Comment: Can you show example of MyTst use in your code?

Comment: so I have two asp.net server controls. One is a textbox and one is an image. When the textbox gets focus I invoke the above mytxt method which changes the source of the asp.net image control to another image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this with the help of JQuery and this website. So it is entirely possible to access server controls through javascript. Here is the helpful page.[enter link description here](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jQuery)

Here is the code I used. I hope it of use to somebody.

```
function MyTst(pVal) {
        var x = document.getElementById($("[id$=" + pVal2 + "]").attr("id"));
        x.src = "/images/write.gif";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the call of the function to make it more flexible

```
MyTst('<%=myTxtBox.ClientID%>') 

function MyTst(pVal2) {           
        var x = document.getElementById(pVal2);
        x.src = "/images/write.gif";      

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about passing element as parameter

```
function MyTst(txtElement) {  

   txtElement.src = "/images/write.gif"; 

}
```

In mark up use `this` like `onclick="MyTst(this)"` to pass current element

**Note**: `src` property belongs to `<img>` tag and not for `<input type=text>`

Comment: Its the the asp.net server control that invokes the method which iam changing. Its another asp.net server control. So I cant use this.

Comment: Sorry I made an error in my example which I have changed. pVal2 being passed in as a parameter as an asp.net image server controls id.